# To convert varbinary(max) to xml format

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, varbinarymax

```
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
```

Can someone guide me to convert the above varbinary(max) to xml format (decrypt) in sql server 2005?

When I tried cast data as xml I get this error:

> XML parsing: line 0, character 0, unrecognized input signature

Comment: It's not XML, its a blob of binary data. 0x1f8b08 is a gzip signature, *is* it gzipped data? if so your better off pulling the data back and using a gzip library in a client language to decompress it

Comment: @Alex how did you know that 0x1f8b08 was the gzip signature

Comment: @Conrad Frix I saw the grouped nulls 000000 @ the beginning so knew it was binary and probably started with a header so I just googled for the 1st 3 bytes

Answer (score 10):

I know it's been a while since you asked this but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
 CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),ColumnName)))
```

I'm using this with good results

Comment: select CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),<ColumnName>))) from <tableName> where <condition>

Answer (score 1):

Alex is correct. If you write out the binary to file and unzip it it contains a file which is an XML file.

Here's the beginning of it

```
<Order xmlns="http://saas.bt.com/v5" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <orderHeader>
  <action>modifyCustomer</action> 
  <status>success</status> 
  <orderKey>fc946a7e-a037-4b12-b86c-8347abb4f842</orderKey> 
  <orderId>a7bd98f1-1355-4fb8-8b1b-00000120c0a8</orderId> 
  <serviceProviderId>1</serviceProviderId> 
  <effectiveDateTime>2009-08-31T08:21:12.5520568+01:00</effectiveDateTime> 
  <orderDateTime>2009-08-31T08:21:12.5520568+01:00</orderDateTime> 
 <customer>
  <action>suspend</action> 
  <status>done</status> 
  <customerKey>1322105</customerKey> 
  <customerId /> 
  <customerStatus i:nil="true" /> 
  <contacts /> 
  <companyName /> 
  <tradingName /> 
  <billingAccounts /> 
  <attributes /> 
  </customer>
 <users>
 <user>
```

What you do with this depends on your needs. For example if you just need this one file you can copy it into the Hex Editor of your choice and save it. Then use a gzip client to decompress it.

If on the other hand you need to migrate the data it will depend on your capabilities and the requirements

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2016, We have an option of COMPRESS(...) and DECOMPRESS(...) function to convert XML to varbinary(max) and vice-versa.